# Plotting in Scatter-plot fomat in Excel

Tags: excel, scatter-plot

I would like to plot the data in the format of scatter.

Sample data:

```
Date_time     Table_1.1 Table_1.2 Table_1.3 Table_1.4 Table_1.5

30/09/2007 09:00    Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Outlier                                     
30/09/2007 10:00    Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Outlier                                     
30/09/2007 11:00    Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal  Normal                                      
30/09/2007 12:00    Outlier Outlier Outlier Outlier Normal                                      
30/09/2007 13:00    Outlier Outlier Normal  Outlier Outlier                                     
30/09/2007 14:00    Outlier Normal  Normal  Outlier Outlier                                     
30/09/2007 15:00    Outlier Normal  Normal  Outlier Outlier                                     
30/09/2007 16:00    Normal  Outlier Normal  Outlier Outlier                                     
30/09/2007 17:00    Normal  Outlier Normal  Normal  Outlier                                     
30/09/2007 18:00    Normal  Outlier Outlier Outlier Normal                                      
30/09/2007 19:00    Outlier Normal  Normal  Outlier Normal                                      
30/09/2007 20:00    Outlier Outlier Outlier Outlier Outlier                                     
30/09/2007 21:00    Outlier Outlier Outlier Outlier Outlier
```

Expected results:

The y-axis should be date-time and Table_1.1~Table1.5 should be located at x-axis and illustrate only the `Outlier`.

Comment: See http://www.ncsu.edu/chemistry/resource/excel/excel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of a chart such as:

[image: SO18062791 example]

is to blank out the data that is not to be plotted (ie Normal) and to assign values to define how far across the x-axis.